# jqGrid Issue – editgridrow with scroll bars

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, scrollbar

I have a little problem with an implementation of the jqGrid in my Web Page.
In a grid I have a lot of columns (10+), and when I want set all these columns to edit and display the edit form, don't display me all the columns.
I want to know if exist a way to set in the edit form, an option to set the vertical and horizontal scrollbars.

Here is the link of the image:
https://picasaweb.google.com/100470218423753226450/Apps#5590653711397752274

Thanks a lot for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching I found the solution of this kind of issues.

Here is the same page, but, with the correct layout:

https://picasaweb.google.com/100470218423753226450/Apps#5590737287949556610

And here is the old code:

```
jQuery("#grid").navGrid("#pager",
        { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false, search: false }, // Options
        {height: 280, width: 650, jqModal: false, closeOnEscape: true }, // Edit options
        {height: 280, width: 650, jqModal: false, closeOnEscape: true }, // Add options
        {}, // Delete options
        {}, // Search options
        {} // View options
    );
```

Now, this is the code to correct the problem:

```
jQuery("#grid").navGrid("#pager",
        { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false, search: false }, // Options
        {dataheight: 200, height: 290, width: 650, jqModal: false, closeOnEscape: true }, // Edit options
        {dataheight: 200, height: 290, width: 650, jqModal: false, closeOnEscape: true }, // Add options
        {}, // Delete options
        {}, // Search options
        {} // View options
    );
```

Exist a property inside the jqgrid that specify the height for the editing controls. It's simple ;)